# How do you use JavaScript to open and close Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website. I am trying to create a navbar dropdown that opens on hover on a desktop and when it is clicked on it takes the user to a new page on the site. On mobile I only want the user to be able to click to open and close the dropdown I don't want them to be taken to a different page. At the moment what I have is a dropdown that opens on hover and leads to another page on desktop. On mobile, when the dropdown is clicked it doesn't lead to another page but when you click on the dropdown to open it you can't close it. I know you need to use JavaScript to fix this but I don't know any JavaScript.

### Desired Dropdown Functionality

#### Desktop/Laptop Dropdown Functionality

- Opens/closes on hover
- when it is clicked on it leads to another page

#### Mobile/Tablet Dropdown Functionality

- Open/closes when clicked
- Doesn't lead to another page.

```css
#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #nav_object::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #nav_object:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_home_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_about_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="nav_service_object">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_contact_object">Contact</a></li>

        
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        <script>
          let serviceNavElement = document.getElementById("nav_service_object")
let isTouch = false
document.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
  console.log("touch")
  isTouch = true
});

serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){
  if(isTouch){
    return
  }
  serviceNavElement.href = "/Bootstrap-/services.html"
  console.log(serviceNavElement)
})

serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(){
  if(isTouch){
    return
  }
  serviceNavElement.href = "#"
  console.log(serviceNavElement)

})
        </script>
       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `script` into your code and add the script file in the `head` tag before the `body` tag closing.

```
<script>
  // Check if the device is a touch device
  let isTouch = false;
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
    isTouch = true;
  });

  // Get the dropdown element
  let serviceNavElement = document.getElementById("nav_service_object");

  // Handle hover behavior on desktop
  serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    if (isTouch) {
      return;
    }
    serviceNavElement.href = "/Bootstrap-/services.html";
  });

  serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    if (isTouch) {
      return;
    }
    serviceNavElement.href = "#";
  });

  // Handle click behavior on mobile
  serviceNavElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (isTouch) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
      let dropdownMenu = this.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
      if (dropdownMenu) {
        dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean I should create a js file insert this code in it and link the file using a `script` tag in the head tag before the `body` tag

Comment: either you can make a separate script.js file and then add the link in the head of the HTML or you can add this code in the body of the HTML code using a script tag like you already did in your HTML file.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work any clue on what the problem might be?

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. try now and tell me if it gives any error.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work this is the link to the codepen.io that has the code because I don't know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: ok drop the link

Comment: https://codepen.io/PatriotsForLife/pen/gOZpLra

Comment: check the href links you provided in the services navbar item. when i click on it on mobile, it's crashing.. Double check that. I,ll try in the morning again

Comment: I am just brainstorming here, but i noticed in the code where you put `dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");` would you need to put something like `dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("hide");` to make it close?

Comment: I was told by someone that the reason the code my comment belowwhy doesn't work is because 1. Attach a click event listener to the window or document (don't know surely).
2. Listen if the clicked element is the modal/dropdown you want to close.
3. Close the modal if the clicked element is not the modal/dropdown

Comment: `<script>
          let serviceNavElement = document.getElementById("nav_service_object")
let isTouch = false
document.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
  console.log("touch")
  isTouch = true
});

serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){
  if(isTouch){
    return
  }
  serviceNavElement.href = "/Bootstrap-/services.html"
  console.log(serviceNavElement)
})

serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(){
  if(isTouch){
    return
  }
  serviceNavElement.href = "#"
  console.log(serviceNavElement)

})
        </script>`

Comment: Is that worked for you?

Comment: no it is the same thing as before it still doesn't work I was just trying to say that I was told to add an event listener that closes the dropdown. You can look at the updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970317/how-do-i-add-an-event-listener-that-closes-the-dropdown
Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: do you have any ideas on a solution?

Comment: the problem is with your boostrap code not javascript. I added the `data-bs-toggle` in the `ul` of `services` and it collapse back but again open due to the javascript you added in the code. I am working on the solution.

Comment: thank you so much please send me the code when you find a solution. I really appreciate all your efforts in helping me.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem because I added `data-bs-toggle` to the services anchor tag because in the bootstrap docs that's how it is supposed to be but it still doesn't work

Comment: anything new? Because I don't know what to try next.